# How can one remove the "Code is unreachable problem". I'm doing this simple code of taking 4 inputs from the user and checking them

Tags: python, input

```
while i <= T:
    T1, T2, R1, R2 = input().split()
    T1 = int(T1)
    T2 = int(T2)
    R1 = int(R1)
    R2 = int(R2)
    
    while True:
        if T1>10 or T1<1:
            print('Enter the value of T1 again, within 1-10 ')
            T1 = int(input())
        elif T2>10 or T2<1:
            print('Enter the value of T2 again, within 1-10 ')
        elif R1>10 or R1<1:
            print('Enter the value of R1 again, within 1-10 ')
        elif R2>10 or R2<1:
            print('Enter the value of R2 again, within 1-10 ')
            
    if T1**2/R1**3 != T2**2/R2**3:
        print('NO')
    else:
        print('YES')
    i=i+1
```

The last 5 lines aren't reachable. I'm using nested while to check the inputs. If you can suggest me some other way, that'll be a great help too

Comment: The loop above the last 5 lines never ends.

Comment: To add to what @mkrieger1 is saying: maybe add e.g. `else: break` to the `if` barrage. (That won't help with re-entering the other values though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True:` creates an infinite loop.

If you want input validation, you can do something like:

```py
while not (1 <= T1 <= 10 and 1 <= T2 <= 10 and 1 <= R1 <= 10 and 1 <= R2 <= 10):
```